# cannot cast from source type to destination type unity solvepnp

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, unity-game-engine

I can't figure out how to solve this error. My code:

```
Mat rotation_vector = new Mat();
Mat translation_vector = new Mat(); 

Calib3d.solvePnP ((OpenCVForUnity.MatOfPoint3f)tmp, (MatOfPoint2f)tmp2, camera_matrix, (MatOfDouble)dist_coeffs, rotation_vector, translation_vector);
```

rotation_vector and translation_vector seem to be the problem. The compiler error is: cannot cast from source type to destination type.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the casts at arguments 1,2 and 4 are wrong?

Comment: There's not much details to help you. Please elaborate more about your issue. What types are `tmp`, `tmp2` and `dist_coeffs`? Whichline is causing error?

Comment: I have found the problem. The matrices tmp and tmp2 had the wrong datatype.